# How to render a webpage using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

How can I get the fully rendered html+css of a client side rendered webpage? The page contents on puppeteer returns a very poorly rendered outcome with missing css

Simplified code:

```
const express = require('express')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

async function getHtml(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url,
        { waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'networkidle2', 'load', 'domcontentloaded'] });
    const k = await page.content()
    await browser.close();
    return k
};

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    getHtml(request.query.url)
        .then(function (res) {
            response.send(res);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err)
            response.send(err);
        })
});

app.listen(port)
```

Running this with any website; for example https://www.tesla.com/ gives something like [image]

Although using the `page.screenshot()` method gives the desired results.

Any ideas on why this occurs? And more importantly, is there a way to get around this behaviour?

Comment: The page content is just HTML, no CSS, JS or other resources the HTML requests. If you render it on a separate front-end, then the paths are pointing cross-origin to Tesla's site and are probably blocked if you open the console.

Comment: Well how can I get around this behaviour?

Comment: You probably can't, aside from maybe downloading all of the assets and serving them yourself. Probably a fool's errand. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: For context, I'd just like to get the html and css. Can do without the js

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to use this as a ssr proxy to get around the html2canvas cross origin policies.

Comment: Maybe try using a proxy like [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).